# Building Python3.6.15 and SQLite-3.20.1 *FROM SOURCE* and Getting Wrong SQLite3 version in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, python-3.6

There are a number of posts about this issue, although most of them do not apply because I am building from source into NON-STANDARD locations.

I'm on CentOS7.

I have compiled/installed sqlite3 from source to a NON-STANDARD location.  Let's call it `/opt/sqlite-3.20.1`.

My Python-3.6.15 configure command is this:

```
%> cd Python-3.6.15
# THIS IS THE DOWNLOADED/UNTARRED SOURCE DIRECTORY
%> mkdir build
%> cd build
%> ../configure \
  -C \
  --prefix=/opt/Python-3.6.15 \
  --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions \
  --enable-optimizations \
  --with-system-ffi \
  --with-ensurepip=install \
  CC="${GCC_HOME}/bin/gcc" \
  CXX="${GCC_HOME}/bin/g++" \
  CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/sqlite-3.20.1/include" \
  LDFLAGS="-L/opt/sqlite-3.20.1/lib" \
  PKG_CONFIG_PATH=PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/libffi-3.4.4/lib/pkgconfig;/opt/sqlite-3.20.1/lib/pkgconfig" \
  ;
%> make -j8
%> make install
```

Once this builds/installs successfully, I see it's linked the wrong sqlite3...

```
%> /opt/Python-3.6.15/bin/python3.6
>>> import sqlite3
>>> print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)
3.7.17
...
%> /opt/sqlite3-3.20.1/bin/sqlite3 --version
3.20.1
%> /usr/bin/sqlite3 --version
3.7.17
```

What am I doing wrong?

Why doesn't `configure` collect information from `pkg_config` instead of having all sorts of random switches like `--with-tcltk-includes` and `--with-system-ffi`?

Thanks!

PS: Oh, and my complier toolchain and some of the libraries (omitted above) are also in a "non-standard" location.